# What is the correct parsing of お高くとまる?

Tags: particles, idioms

I had always thought that the phrase `お高くとまる` consisted of the adverbial `お高く` combined with the verb `とまる`. I never actually paid much attention to the literal meaning since it is obviously a figurative phrase (meaning 'to assume an air of importance').  However, I noticed in a dictionary that the `と` might actually be an adverbial `と` rather than being part of the verb. See below:

[image]

In the 例文 example, it is written in katakana as `ト`, presumably to differentiate it from `まる`. So I searched for the verb `まる` (lemma) but I could only find one instance:

[image]

The doesn't seem to make sense in the context unless the meaning is derived from something like "to excrete from a high place" or something like that. Maybe that's possible?

So is it `とまる` (one word) or is it `～（と）まる` (particle plus verb)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm curious which dictionary you used to find that odd kana-ization?

Searching for the kana string おたかくとまる over on [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/), a decent online dictionary aggregator sourcing from reputable native-language Japanese dictionaries, gives us [several relevant pages](https://kotobank.jp/gs/?q=%E3%81%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B).  The [Nihon Kokugo Dai Jiten entry for the 御高くとまる spelling](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BE%A1%E9%AB%98%E3%81%A8%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B-2016506) includes the following sample sentence from the 1898 novel 恋慕【れんぼ】ながし by 小【お】栗【ぐり】風【ふう】葉【よう】:

> 悪【わる】くお高【たか】くばかり留【とま】ってゐりやがって

We also find [an entry in the same dictionary for 高【たかく】止【と】まる](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%AB%98%E6%AD%A2%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B-2058785), with alternative older Western-influenced reading たこうとまる, and a quote from the 1686 work 好【こう】色【しょく】一【いち】代【だい】女【おんな】:

> 高【たか】ふとまって鶏【けい】鳴【めい】別【わか】れにも客【きゃく】ををくらず

Then in [the Daijirin entry for 止まる・留まる・止る・留る・停まる](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%AD%A2%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E7%95%99%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E7%95%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E5%81%9C%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B-343205) (all various spellings of とまる), we see a note at the bottom of the entry:

> **［慣用］** お高く－ ・ 御【お】目【め】に－ ／目にも留まらぬ

We have multiple entries in at least two different dictionaries from separate publishers, all indicating that the とまる is the verb, and not adverbial と + some other verb まる.  So ultimately, I think the online dictionary you referenced has a typo.

**PS:** Grammatically, adverbial と after an adjective in the adverbial ～く form would be very odd.  That said, language is a human affair and thus inevitably messy and full of oddness, so it's best to check.  :)

Comment: It was the ＮＨＫ 日本語発音アクセント辞典 which had the erroneous katakana. Given the evidence in your answer, I tend to agree with you that it must be a typo.

Comment: I’m not sure why, but that is how the NHK accent dictionary behaves on all entries that have a parenthesized suffix. The first character of the suffix becomes katakana, and the rest hiragana.

Comment: How perfectly odd.  Makes me wonder if there was some sort of algorithmic hiccup there?  I just perused the 凡例 of my electronic version, and there's no explanation of the change between katakana and hiragana that's evident in some entries.